# Benchmark for a rowlock in mysql

Tags: mysql, benchmarking, amazon-aurora

I am trying to benchmark a sql transaction with a select..for update statement which uses an exclusive lock on the row and then insert a row into another table as shown below.

```
START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT CurrentSize
    FROM testtable
    WHERE id = {id} FOR UPDATE;

    -- update current size in testtable
    UPDATE testtable
    SET currentsize = currentsize + 1
    WHERE id = {id} ;
    -- insert into a different table
    insert into testtable2 values(1,2);
 COMMIT;
```

I am getting 2K tps for the above transaction and I am assuming each transaction takes 0.5ms to complete so giving me 2K tps .

Is it even possible to scale the system beyond this point? If yes is there any implementation that I could try and use.

I am using a 16x.large machine of AWS RDS Aurora MySQL.